# How to set index value to Form in Angular 7 using FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

unable to set index value from for loop to form control in the angular without using ng-model is there any way to accomplish it ?

```
<div formArrayName="sample" *ngFor="let a of getControls(sampledata, 'sample'); let i = index">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input type="text" formControlName="index" name="index" value="{{ i }}" 
  />
  <input
      formControlName="dx"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
//form Group
this.sampledata= new FormGroup({
      sample: new FormArray([this.createArray()])
    });

//Form Array
createArray(){
return this.formBuilder.group({
      dx: null,
      index:null
    })

//Creation of array dynamically
getControls(frmGrp: FormGroup, key: string) {
  return (<FormArray>frmGrp.controls[key]).controls;
}
```

Comment: can you also mention your formgroup?

Comment: hi @ng-suhas check out my question it is updated with from group

Comment: I have given my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using property binding

```
<div formArrayName="sample" *ngFor="let a of sampledata; let i = index">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input type="text" formControlName="i" name="i" [value]="i" 
  />
  <input
      formControlName="dx"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my `formControlName` is **index** only and i need to set value of **i** for it.

Comment: @GaganV Try updated answer and you need unique name for each formControl.

Comment: no errors index value is not setting to input value, if we manually add input it is getting value

Answer (score 0):

There are some points you have missed in your code,

Because you are dealing with the `dynamic input tags`, you need to give the `unique name` to `formControlName` and that can be done with below code.

**P.S :** For value you don't need to add `{{}}`.

```
 <div formArrayName="sample" *ngFor="let a of sampledata; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="index_{{i}}">
        <input type="text" formControlName="index_{{i}}" name="index_{{i}}" value="i"/>
        <input formControlName="dx_{{i}}"  type="text"  class="form-control"  />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: since our `formGroupName` is unique it won't make any issue with with same `formControlName ` as i'm getting value for input

Comment: Nope `*ngfor` index value is not setting to input value, if we manually add input it is getting  value

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` should be placed after defining the formArray Name. You should change your html like below,

```
<div formArrayName="samples">
    <div *ngFor="let a of getControls(sampledata, 'sample'); let i = index"
           [formGroupName]="i">
    <input type="text" formControlName="index" name="index" value="{{ i }}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should bind the value of i to your formControlName index.

Hope it helps. Cheers

Here is the working sample from stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbqtmj